# low speed working with swiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift

I'm using SwiftyJSON pod and I got a JSON like this :
[image]

I'm using a simple for loop in this JSON. but the problem is that it has a very low speed, it takes about 4 seconds to do this for loop. 
this my code :

```
 for _ in jsonDariafti!["contacts"]{

                if (jsonDariafti!["contacts"][i]["name"].stringValue.range(of: txtSearch.text!) != nil)  {
                    arrayINdexPathSearch.append(i)
                }
                i = i + 1

            }
```

I'm trying to do a search in this JSON. for each word that user typed he has to wait about 4 seconds. I use below for loop and change it to an array and then searched in array. it works fine. but still very low in the initial for loop, it takes about 5 seconds :

```
    for _ in jsonDariafti!["contacts"]{

             arraySearch.append(jsonDariafti!["contacts"][i]["name"].stringValue)
                i = i + 1

            }
```

is there any better way using JSONS? or any advice using JSONs?

**edit :**
this is how I get JSON:

```
#import SwiftyJSON
#import Alamofire 


func getdata(){
    Alamofire.request("http://rsptint.ir/getSefaresh.php", method: .get).responseJSON {
        response in
        if  response.result.isSuccess {
            self.jsonDariafti = JSON(response.result.value!)

        } else{
            self.showAlert(message: "مشکل در ارتباط با اینترنت")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: While this could be improved a lot (you should not search over JSON in the first place, you should parse JSON once to objects and then search in objects), I don't think it could cause a 4s delay. That's just too much.

Comment: You do not show how what type your `jsonDariafti` variable is, nor how you parse it. There is quite a lot of other things that might go wrong except searching. Please tell us some more.

Comment: @Sulthan It really cause 4s delay. I don't parse my JSON. I just use it with swiftyJSON pod. should I use another way?

Comment: @Patru forget about searching. the second for-loop that I wrote, I run it separately  and it still take 4s.

Comment: I tend to believe your account after I tried pasting your JSON into a Playground. This basically ground it to a halt! After tedious whittling down and the introduction of newlines I got it to say something sensible like `Expected hexadecimal code in braces after unicode escape`. When I added the braces it started to look more normal (but I _had to_ add them manually, no search and replace would work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend ditching SwiftyJSON and the string-and-dictionary based searching you're doing, and replacing this with much simpler code based on `Codable`.

```
struct Sefaresh: Codable {
    let contacts: [Contact]
}

struct Contact: Codable {
    let code, name, id, carton, tedad, litr, vahed, vazn: String
}

let sefaresh = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Sefaresh.self, from: jsonData)
```

your first loop then becomes

```
for (index, contact) in sefaresh.contacts.enumerated() {
   if contact.stringValue.range(of: txtSearch.text!) != nil {
     arrayIndexPathSearch.append(index)
   }
}
```

and the second is simply

```
for contact in sefaresh.contacts {
    arraySearch.append(contact.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer, but rather an elaboration on the question, but with a lot of mangling and tweaking I got the following to work:

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
{ "contacts": [
  {"code":"AC60-12","name":"\u{0633}\u{0641}\u{06cc}\u{062f} \u{067e}\u{0644}\u{06cc} \u{0627}\u{0648}\u{0631}\u{0647} \u{062a}\u{0627}\u{0646}-\u{06a9}\u{0627}\u{0631}\u{062a}\u{0646} 12\u{062a}\u{0627}\u{06cc}\u{06cc}","id":"5","carton":"1","tedad":"12","litr":"12","vahed":"","vazn":"1"},
  {"code":"AC60-6","name":"\u{0633}\u{0641}\u{06cc}\u{062f} \u{067e}\u{0644}\u{06cc} \u{0627}\u{0648}\u{0631}\u{0647} \u{062a}\u{0627}\u{0646}-\u{06a9}\u{0627}\u{0631}\u{062a}\u{0646} 6\u{062a}\u{0627}\u{06cc}\u{06cc}","id":"4","carton":"1","tedad":"6","litr":"6","vahed":"","vazn":"1"},
  {"code":"ME1019","name":"Brilliant White \u{06cc}\u{06a9} \u{0644}\u{06cc}\u{062a}\u{0631}\u{06cc} ME 1019","id":"516","carton":"1","tedad":"6","litr":"6","vahed":"","vazn":"1"}]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Sefaresh: Codable {
    let contacts: [Contact]
}

struct Contact: Codable {
    let code, name, id, carton, tedad, litr, vahed, vazn: String
}

do {
    let sefaresh = try JSONDecoder().decode(Sefaresh.self, from: jsonData)
    print(sefaresh)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This looks even more horrible, but it might also point out some of the problems you encountered. It might have to do with the typical encoding of a Playground (which is UTF-8), but even then it compiles properly and the result contains a lot of characters which seem to originate from the same script as you posted.

While getting there I had to cope with a lot of errors during `String` parsing like

```
Expected hexadecimal code in braces after unicode escape
```

and I was only able to correct that manually, any search/replace pattern would fail and even after the introduction of the curly braces the editor would sometimes only search like a drag. You seem to have hit upon something that can thoroughly confuse Xcode or even the Swift `String` parser in general (though much less likely, since the Playground runs very quickly once it compiles without error).

I am not sure who or what created your escaped JSON in the first place, but if it was a language which still assumes that your unicode characters should all fit within 16 bits that might explain something.

Would you care to elaborate what created your JSON in the first place? Given my experience with the Playground (it became completely unresponsive until I started introducing newlines) I can easily believe that you triggered some edge case of Swifts `String` parsing. Given so many escapes in a form that Swift might not understand I am pretty sure anything might happen.

If it is possible to introduce newlines after the end of your `contacts` that could help and of course the braces would make all the difference since they seem to be the way Swift expects your escapes to come. Maybe some other encoding (like UTF-16?) might help, but I am not versed well enough with the workings of non-latin scripts to really be able to tell.